# Eigenvalues of $(T^*T)^{1/2}$ for a compact operator $T$

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, compact-operators

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, what are the eigenvalues of $(T^*T)^{1/2}$ in terms of the eigenvalues of a compact operator $T: \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H},$ where $T^*$ denotes the adjoint of $T$?

I want to contrast a result stated in terms of the eigenvalues of $(T^*T)^{1/2}$ to another result stated in terms of the eigenvalues of $T$. I am mainly interested in expressing the convergence of $\sum_k (\frac{1}{\lambda_k})^{-\nu}$ (where $\lambda_k$ is the $k-$th eigenvalue of $(T^*T)^{1/2}$ in descending order and $\nu$ is a real number) in terms of the eigenvalues of $T$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: As @JoséCarlosSantos suggested  give more context.  In particular explain what kind of relation  you expect and possibly give examples if you studied any.

Comment: There is a serious obstacle. Let $T:\ell^2\to \ell^2$ be defined by $$T(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(0, 2^{-1}x_1,2^{-2}x_2,\ldots)$$
Then $T$ is a compact operator with no eigenvalues. However
$$(T^*T)^{1/2}(x_1,x_2,\ldots )= (2^{-1}x_1,2^{-2}x_2,\ldots )$$ So the set of eigenvalues of $(T^*T)^{1/2}$ coincides with the sequence $\{2^{-n}\}_{n=1}^\infty.$

Comment: Look for *singular numbers*.